# A easy way to set up a stand-alone Cloudera HBase 5?

Tags: hbase, cloudera

I know that I can download hbase from apache like hbase-0.98.1-hadoop1-bin.tar.gz in http://archive.apache.org/dist/hbase/hbase-0.98.1/, then unzip it, and just run start-hbase.sh to start up the hbase.

But what if I need a Cloudera HBase, like CDH5, how to set up a stand alone CDH5, is there a easy way to do it? All I want is a stand alone Cloudera HBase, not the whole Cloudera platform.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most easiest way to get Cloudera environment is through their sandbox's from [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/DemoVMs/Cloudera-QuickStart-VM/cloudera_quickstart_vm.html).

But, if you just want Cloudera's version of Hbase you use Cloudera's tar ball's from [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh5/v5-0-0/CDH-Version-and-Packaging-Information/cdhvd_cdh_package_tarball.html) and extract like you would do for Apache Hadoop.

Take a look at this interesting offering from Cloudera called as [Cloudera Live](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products-and-services/cloudera-live.html)

Comment: Thanks a million for the tar ball link, that is what I need. BTW, do you know where I can find Hortonworks 2.1 Hbase tar ball?

Comment: The closest that I could found was HDP 2.0.9 [here](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.9.1/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap13.html). But from my understanding HortonWorks HDP 2 closely relates to the Apache Hadoop 2.2 so, you just have to know which versions are used in a particular HDP version, which could be found [here](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1.5/bk_releasenotes_hdp_2.1/content/ch_relnotes-hdp-2.1.1-product.html)

Comment: From your second link, I can see something like "Apache HBase 0.98.0", does that mean "Hortonworks 2.1 Hbase" and "Apache HBase 0.98.0" are actually identical? Doesn't Hortonworks do any further developemnt on "Apache HBase 0.98.0" when they delivery HDP 2.1?

Comment: Yes HDP does not add any proprietary code on top of open source Hadoop. So, hortonworks 2.1 HBase and Apache HBase are actually identical.

Comment: Thank you Ashrith, for your detailed explanation.